# How to get local time in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get `printed date` which should be the local time of the browser.When I am running it on the local server it gets me the correct time but when I push my code on the Dev server, it gets me the UTC time. Not sure how to proceed

in template:
`<p>Generated&nbsp;&nbsp;{{today|date:'short'}}</p>`

in Typescript file:
`today: number = new Date();`

Comment: According to the docs, the code you have should use the user's timezone. https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#parameters. The server shouldn't matter since the `new Date()` code should run in the user's browser. What is the context of that code? Is it actually part of the Angular app, or is it part of some API running on the server?

Comment: It's the part of ANGULAR APP.

Comment: Taking the code you've given literally, it does display the date in the user's timezone. See https://angular-1xuvcz.stackblitz.io, edit at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1xuvcz.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. 
It does shoe local time when I run it locally on mhy machine, once I push the code to a different environment/Dev Zone, it starts spitting out UTC time.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen -  Actually,  I just figured out that PDF[Since I am printing my date on the PDF] is generated on server side (including rendering in the browser), so that's why it's getting the local time of the server and not the  browser

Answer (score 0):

The date pipe takes a timezone parameter so you can just defined your timezone of choice.

`{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

Comment: In US, there are multiple timezones, keeping this in mind, how can i make this work>